# Is it possible to override spring-security-config in an SAP hybris Addon?

Tags: spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, add-on

I'm developing an Addon to add WebAuthn-Authentication to the standard hybris electronics store. I need to override the spring-security-config.xml. Is it possible to do this in that context or do I have to implement a new extension?

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://answers.sap.com/questions/12751594/view.html which talks about a similar problem.